# How to render the page based on selected option on the middle part of App, Top and side bar should be static

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Sorry if the title is kinda confusing.
I'm making an index page with a side and top navbar with the menu using react router, I have successfully loaded the content up but I want it to load in the main body, the middle of the page.

I've tried separating method like how I used JSP before but its not very effective so to speak

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Login from './Login';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import './index.css';
import AssetView from './AssetView';
import DepartmentView from './DepartmentView';
import LocationView from './LocationView';
import EmployeeView from './EmployeeView';
import AddDepartment from './AddDepartment';
import AddLocation from './AddLocation';

const routing = (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
  <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">Company name</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
        Account
      </Dropdown.Toggle>
      <Dropdown.Menu>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Informations</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Settings</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Signout</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-sticky">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-Link active" href="#">
              <span data-feather="home"></span>
              Dashboard <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>

                  <h6 className="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
                  <span>Assets Management</span>
                  <a className="d-flex align-items-center text-muted" href="#">
                    <span data-feather="plus-circle" />
                  </a>
                </h6>
                <li className="nav-item">
                      <Link to="/AssetView">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file"></span>
                      View All Assets
                      </a>
                      </Link>
                  </li>

                </ul>

                <h6 className="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
                  <span>Company Management</span>
                  <a className="d-flex align-items-center text-muted" href="#">
                    <span data-feather="plus-circle" />
                  </a>
                </h6>
                <ul className="nav flex-column mb-2">
                  <li className="nav-item">
                      <Link to="/DepartmentView">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file"></span>
                      View All Departments
                      </a>
                      </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                      <Link to="/AddDepartment">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file"></span>
                      Add New Department
                      </a>
                      </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                      <Link to="/LocationView">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file"></span>
                      View All Locations
                      </a>
                      </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to="/AddLocation">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file"></span>
                      Add New Location
                      </a>
                      </Link>
                  </li>
        </ul>

                <h6 className="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
                  <span>Employees Management</span>
                  <a className="d-flex align-items-center text-muted" href="#">
                    <span data-feather="plus-circle" />
                  </a>
                </h6>
                <ul className="nav flex-column mb-2">
                  <li className="nav-item">
                      <Link to="/EmployeeView">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file"></span>
                      View All Employees
                      </a>
                      </Link>
                  </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
      <Route exact path="/AssetView" component={AssetView} />
        <Route path="/DepartmentView" component={DepartmentView} />
        <Route path="/LocationView" component={LocationView} />
        <Route path="/EmployeeView" component={EmployeeView} />
        <Route path="/AddDepartment" component={AddDepartment} />
        <Route path="/AddLocation" component={AddLocation} />

      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )

  ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

This is how the page looks right now, I really wish to make the content of the page appear in the middle

https://photos.app.goo.gl/BSuZuvGhiQQetmit5

Comment: If the title is confusing you can edit it. Sorry I don't get the issue

Comment: sorry about, I'll try to edit the title to be a little more understandable

Comment: Thank you @piyush-dhamecha for the suggested edits

Comment: You need some sort of `CSS` to do this. Remove `sidebar-sticky` class and try to add `css` to your sidebar like `.sidebar{position:absolute,top:0,bottom:0}`.

Comment: @HarryVũ check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer has been replied by @ravibagul91, thank you.

I removed the `class="sidebar-sticky"` of the sidebar and add the `.sidebar{position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0}` in my index.css and it works just fine as the image I just uploaded

https://photos.app.goo.gl/m744U7R4mACAUXq37

Thank you @piyush-dhamecha for the recommendation, it is somewhat similar to what I need, but truth be told, it's still kinda advance for me, but I appreciate it and will keep it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you have to create a dashboard-like app
Where top and sidebar is static and on click of the sidebar the middle part change

Then you can check this repo
https://github.com/designrevision/shards-dashboard-react

Here is the master page https://github.com/DesignRevision/shards-dashboard-react/blob/master/src/layouts/Default.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "shards-react";

import MainNavbar from "../components/layout/MainNavbar/MainNavbar";
import MainSidebar from "../components/layout/MainSidebar/MainSidebar";
import MainFooter from "../components/layout/MainFooter";

const DefaultLayout = ({ children, noNavbar, noFooter }) => (
  <Container fluid>
    <Row>
      <MainSidebar />
      <Col
        className="main-content p-0"
        lg={{ size: 10, offset: 2 }}
        md={{ size: 9, offset: 3 }}
        sm="12"
        tag="main"
      >
        {!noNavbar && <MainNavbar />}
        {children}
        {!noFooter && <MainFooter />}
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
);

DefaultLayout.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Whether to display the navbar, or not.
   */
  noNavbar: PropTypes.bool,
  /**
   * Whether to display the footer, or not.
   */
  noFooter: PropTypes.bool
};

DefaultLayout.defaultProps = {
  noNavbar: false,
  noFooter: false
};

export default DefaultLayout;
```